# setting a value using ISNULL?

Tags: sql-server, isnull

I know this is simple but I really need to make sure what I understood is indeed correct.

Is the below code setting the value of `A.FUTUREUSE09` to 'not available' if `DS.[FUTUREUSE09] IS NULL`?

```
UPDATE A  
   SET  
       A.[FUTUREUSE09] = ISNULL(DS.[FUTUREUSE09] , 'not available')  
       ----------  
       -----------  
       -----------  
       -----------  
FROM PRODUCT A JOIN DS_PRODUCTS DS  
ON A.ID = DS.ID  
JOIN HIERARCHY H ON   
                            CASE      
                             WHEN DS.CODE = 'not available' THEN 'NA_PL3'  
                             ELSE DS.CODE  
                            END = H.CODE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It will. `ISNULL` takes 2 parameters: First is a *check_expression* and second is *replacement_value*. It returns the first check_expression if it is not null else it returns replacement_value, in your case **not available**

Comment: okay,,, so if DS.[FUTUREUSE09] is not null then A.[FUTUREUSE09] will be set to DS.[FUTUREUSE09] ??

Comment: Cool. If this solved your issue, please accept the answers to avoid duplicate questions being asked by others later